# curl error: couldn't connect to host

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use curl with a proxy. I have the following code:

```
function getPage($proxy, $url, $referer, $agent, $header, $timeout) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

$result['EXE'] = curl_exec($ch);
$result['INF'] = curl_getinfo($ch);
$result['ERR'] = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

return $result;
}

$result = getPage(
'75.125.147.82:3128', // use valid proxy
'http://www.google.com/',
'http://www.google.com/',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8',
1,
5);

if (empty($result['ERR'])) {
echo $results['EXE'];
} else {
echo $result['ERR'];
}
```

The output of this script is 'couldn't connect to host'

Anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: Is error reporting turned on? Have you tried connecting to different host addresses, (not using proxy)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well
delete this code

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
```

it works for me,I'm testing this code as well
good luck

Answer (score 4):

You might check what the status code is of where you're connecting to:

```
$status = curl_getinfo($http, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Might give you an idea of what is going on.